# what does fifth argument "send_handle" mean in uv_write2

Tags: libuv

I looked up the document of libuv, there's no explaination about what it is used for:https://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/stream.html#c.uv_write2

There are two handles in arguments of uv_write2. The first one I guess means the target fd we want to write to. But the second one *send_handle*, I can't understand.

I also read on the source code of libuv. I found that *send_handle* was not used, it's only assign to the *send_handle* attribute of the first argument *uv_write_t req*.

I want to know what's the meaning of "send_handle"

Comment: I believe its only purpose is to write a multi-threaded server. The detailed usage can be found [here](https://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/guide/processes.html#sending-file-descriptors-over-pipes).